# Request geolocation in ionic 4

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to get coordinates of my device location using the cordova geolocation plugin.
When running the app on android (10), I get prompted for location permissions which I set to always allow and after that my getLocation function gets executed but I don't get any of the additional feedback which I programmed in to suggest that it has actually received coordinates. 
For the moment don't focus on the loadMap component, my focus currently is to retrieve coordinates,

I already did the import in app.module.ts
This is my home.page.ts
(For debug purposes I chained together the loadMap function and getLocation function to make sure the getLocation function gets executed (which it does judging by the begin location flow message I receive)

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation} from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
// Import classes from maps module
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  LatLng,
  MarkerOptions,
  Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

import { Platform, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
lat;
lng;
  constructor( public platform: Platform, public nav: NavController, private geolocation: Geolocation ) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.platform.ready().then( () => {

      this.loadMap();

    });
    this.getLocation();
  }
  loadMap() {
    console.log('map render start');
    let map = GoogleMaps.create( 'map' );

    map.one( GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY ).then( ( data: any ) => {

      let coordinates: LatLng = new LatLng( 50.7783, 119.4179 );

      let position = {
        target: coordinates,
        zoom: 14
      };

      map.animateCamera( position );

      let markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
        position: coordinates,
        icon: "assets/images/marker.png",
        title: 'Hello California'
      };

      const marker = map.addMarker( markerOptions )
          .then( ( marker: Marker ) => {
            marker.showInfoWindow();
          });
    });
    this.getLocation();
  }

  getLocation() {
    console.log('begin location flow');
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
  // resp.coords.latitude
  // resp.coords.longitude
    this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
    this.lng = resp.coords.longitude;
    alert('lat' + this.lat + 'lon' + this.lng);
    console.log('location succes');
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error getting location', error);
});
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your Device GPS is ON? if Not you can Check with this Plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/location-accuracy

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Yes my Location services are on on High Accuracy. I will currently try using your plugin

Comment: I struggle with location a couple of years ago. I have not implemented using Ionic4, but at that moment I work a solution using both GeoLocation and [BackgroundGeolocation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation). Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

you need to move the method your calling that makes use of the native plugin into the platform ready promise call back. Native plugins cannot be used until this fires.

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
 this.getLocation();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code above, you're calling `this.getLocation()` twice, as you pointed out, however, the first/initial `this.getLocation()` call gets run probably before `this.platform.ready()` (see `ngAfterViewInit()` routine).

Could this cause a conflict?

Comment: Actually, it only fires the console output associated with that function once. So I don't know what's happening. I'll try @EvanThomas' solution